# Can i add two Google Analytics account to one android project

Tags: android, google-analytics

my requirement is to add two Google Anlytics Account in to one Android App. So, both different account person can able to track the analytics separately.
If anyone know this thing then please tell me how to implement.
Thank you

Comment: So Simple, create one app with one account and share ID & Password to both persons.

Comment: Thank you Shane, but the problem is need to create analytics with two different account.

Comment: Ask your question here --> https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics/ct-p/analytics_category and also read https://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html

Answer (score 1):

Currently as per google document we can not implement google analytics with two different accounts into a single android project.